# How does electron localization/delocalization work?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory

I can't find a simplified explanation on this topic. My textbook just adds to the confusion and all I'm really left with are more questions rather than answers.

And adding to that question, does polarity have an effect on electron localization/delocalization?

Comment: In general terms, looking through the meaning of the terms, it seems that, delocalization of electrons refers to something which is not restricted to a particular atom (we can expect this in metallic bonds). Whereas, localization is the opposite of that, where we find electrons restricted to a particular atom (we can expect this in covalent bonds). I am not strictly speaking, but seeing through the terms, I have this opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Draw the LCAO orbitals.  Delocalization is the summation of discrete electron occupations of orbitals, such as a 1,3 shift (a pi-bond flip).  Remember that LCAO is a terrifically wrong black box. Its only virtue is that it simply, beautifully works (until the Woodward-Hoffmann rules).

Given propene, abstract a methyl proton.  The LCAO anion is half at both ends by a 1,3-shift of the pi bond.  MO shows degenerate orbital occupation still with (nearly) no additional density at the central carbon.  Abstract an allylic proton from 1-butene.  The allylic ends are no longer 50:50 occupied by the anion for the different electronic properties of two attached protons versus a methyl group and a proton.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simplified explanation, and especially not of "how it works". The behavior of electrons is governed by quantum mechanics. So electrons do what they do, because it is energetically favorable. It should become quite clear upon obtaining master degree in theoretical chemistry ;)

As a teaser, I'd at least show the pictures:

- Localized sigma bond, localized means it is as compact in space, as possible, now connecting two carbon atoms in ethane:

[image: Localized sigma bond]

- Delocalized pi electrons in benzene, shared by 6 atoms:

[image]